# How to make a caption with images in jquery gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, caption

I have an image gallery that I'm working on

example: http://imagethrow.com/design-studio-all-throws.html

right now it only displays images, I'd like to have it so each image has a caption either above or below the image.

this is the html part of the gallery:

```
<a class="imgLink" href="path-to-the-image.jpg">Image name</a>
<img src="" id="theImage">
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.imgLink').click(function(){
    var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#theImage').attr('src',imgPath);
    return false;
    });
});
```

If it's possible to tweak the above code to add a caption that would be ideal.

Comment: What do you want the caption to be? The anchor text?

Comment: I don't want it to be clickable, just a line or so of text describing the images.

Comment: Yes, but *where is the text for the caption coming from*?

Comment: @user3237758 As David asked, where would the description come from? If it's different than the `<a>` tag you click on, then probably the best way is to add a data-attribute on your `<a>` tag. What browsers are you looking to support??

Comment: I'd like it to come from the <a> tag you click on.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add a new html tag to contain that caption, you could use a div for example
2. Add the jquery code to select that div and change the text

Here you have an example: http://goo.gl/h8JJk3

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. How would I edit this to have a different caption for each image?